# How can a document with version "1.0" have a status of "Draft"?

Tags: powershell, document, version

I have a set of documents which appear to have no problems in the browser, but when I inspect the properties of the document in PowerShell, it reveals that it is actually a Draft document:

```
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem = $list.items[6]
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem.level
Draft
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem["Version"]
1.0
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem.versions.count
1
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem.versions[0]["Version"]
1.0
PS C:\Users\nacht> $listitem.versions[0].level
Draft
```

This was an issue for me as I had a script that finds the **LatestPublishedVersion** of documents, relying on the **"Level" property**. I have since fixed this issue simply by republishing these documents, but I am still curious how these documents got in this state. The library has **versioning settings** set to not require content approval, **"Create major versions"** only, **"Any user who can read items"** can see draft items, and don't require check out to edit.

Anyone know how these documents could have gotten into this state?

Comment: Couldn't this happen if, at some point, you switched from major/minor versioning to major-only versioning? Doc with minor version (i.e. with a draft level) would be promoted to a major version, but maybe the level is not updated...

Comment: No, SharePoint seems to get this situation right - when I try this out, the documents are listed as `Published`.